# Linux CAN socket - handle error frames

Tags: linux, can-bus

I know that if there is an error in a [CAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus) transmission, the system will generate a particular error frame. But I can't figure how to make this working.

I set up my CAN socket, and then I write data:

```
write(s, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr))
```

There is nothing connected on the bus, so I would expect a CAN_ERR_ACK, but nothing arrive.

PS: error receiving is enabled.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You might have to enable error receiving

```
can_err_mask_t err_mask = CAN_ERR_ACK ;
setsockopt(skt, SOL_CAN_RAW, CAN_RAW_ERR_FILTER,&err_mask, sizeof(err_mask));
```

Comment: I forgot to write that error receiving is enabled, but I can't receive the error frame.
I hava no devices connected on the wire..May this can be a problem?

Comment: In this case my hardware generates CAN_ERR_CRTL (in can_id) and CAN_ERR_CRTL_RX_WARNING . Check what is going on using candump

Comment: this is the situation:
    `./cansend can0 55 55 55` 
in the other terminal, candump responds with
    `<0x001> [3] 37 37 37`

No error frames...

Comment: @rPulvi Did you enabled filtering of all frames in candump? candump -tA any,0:0,#FFFFFFF . If you dont see error you might have enabled loopback, or driver issues, or somebody is ack-ing packets.

Comment: Nothing to do.. I can see only the frame I send, no error frames.
Filtering is on and loopback is off.

Comment: I have no other devices connected onto CANbus..can this be the problem? I'expecting to receive error frames anyway. Am I wrong?

Comment: I think you are right.  I am not expert, but Can interfaces in MCU-s or external ones generates error/HW-interrupt when number of TX errors exceeds number 96. It looks like that you have not fully supported drivers. What is your hardware, i am using PCAN-USB  from Peak?

Comment: I'm using a Karo TX25. Reading the kernel log I can see that bus go to off state after sending the first message.

Comment: @rPulvi It's late but... have you noticed that 55 = 0x37?